# Coredata memory leak: Deinit does not get called.. causing memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, memory-leaks, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am saving messages into coredata, and when I leave the controller it doesn't deinit. It's also causing a memory leak that gets bigger and bigger everytime I present a new controller with the function inside.

```
func saveMessagetoCoreData(text: String, timestamp: NSNumber, status: String, friend: Friend) {

    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let doubletimestamp = Double(timestamp)
    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: (doubletimestamp))

    createMessageWithText(text, friend: friend, context: moc, date: date, status: "...")
    do {
        try moc.save()
        //moc.reset()

    } catch let err {
        print(err)
    }


private func createMessageWithText(text: String, friend: Friend, context: NSManagedObjectContext, date: NSDate, isSender: Bool = false, status: String) -> Mesages {
    let message = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Mesages", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Mesages

    message.user = friend
    message.text = text
    message.timestamp = date
    message.isSender = isSender
    message.status = status
    message.fromID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("FBid") as! String
    friend.lastMessage = message

    return message

}
```

when the message is saved into coredata, if i dismiss the viewcontroller, it deinit does not get called anymore.

anyone have any idea to what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Any memory leak is probably caused by a circular reference in your code. The following two lines look suspicious...

```
    message.user = friend
    ...
    friend.lastMessage = message
```

`message.user` points to `friend`, and `friend.lastMessage` points to `message`. As long as they're getting released you should be ok though. What is holding a reference to your view controller?

Comment: hi, how do you release them?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by what's holding reference to your viecontroller , if i understand correctly, the previous controller holds a reference to it to transfer the users information to next controller

Comment: by the way, this only happens when I send a message

Comment: Did you able to fix this? What is the solution?

Comment: for me this helped https://gist.github.com/nor0x/c48463e429ba7b053fff6e277c72f8ec